# Override constructor in Perl Class::Accessor

Tags: perl, oop

### Premise

The question is difficult to understand, due to a misunderstanding of the OO logic in perl by me, the OP. The comments can be useful to understand it.

### Original question

The `Class::Accessor` module is extremely convenient for me, but I can't find any documentation about how to write a constructor such that I can, for instance, derive the values for a field out of some computation.

The closest thing I can think of, with the given documentation, is passing trough a "sort of" override:

```
package FooHack;

...
use Class::Accessor 'antlers';
has something => ( is => 'ro' );

# Methods here...

package Foo; # Foo is a plain module, not a class.

sub new { 
    my $macguffin = &crunch_chop_summon;
    FooHack->new({something => $macguffin });
}
```

This kinda works, except `my $f = Foo->new(); say ref $f` will yield `FooHack` instead of `Foo`.

So my questions are:

- Is my idea good enough or do you see some possible issues with it? Or maybe some improvements?
- Is there a better way of doing the same thing?

### Edit:

This is *NOT* an actual override. `Foo` is nowhere a class. It's just a plain module declaring a `sub new`. Plus, the module `FooHack` is not an external module. It is defined within the very same file.

The module `Foo` pretends to be a class in that it follows the convention of having a `sub new`, while `new` is actually just a function which calls the real constructor, `FooHack->new` and passes some initialization value for it.

Comment: It sounds like you just want the rest of `Moose`. `Class::Accessor` was never meant to provide a comprehensive object-oriented framework — just, as its name suggests, accessor methods for object attributes

Comment: @Borodin, I would like to accept your answer, but first you should review it, since It is misleading (see my edit to the question)

Comment: I don't see that my solution is misleading. All that is required for a Perl class is that the code be in its own package and there be a `new` or equivalent class constructor method. You have written a class.

Comment: If you want to insist that, somehow, this Perl class mustn't be used as such, then you must explain what non-standard behaviour you want from `package Foo`. It will help if you explain what your `package Foo` statement is for, if not to define a class

Comment: I thought that a class requires a bless or an inheritance, and that the name `new` is purely conventional. If you tell me this is wrong then your answer is correct. Also I will definitely use `Moose` as you suggest.

Comment: Anywhere that you call, say, `AaBb->method(0, 42)` it is directly equivalent to `AaBb::method('AaBb', 0, 42)`. Defining `@ISA` is only to implement the object-oriented *inheritance* design pattern

Comment: @Borodin, thanks, this is the kind of answer I was searching for! I was not aware of this fact. Then I've got an acceptance for you. I'm just sorry I took so much time from you.

Comment: I have no problem with the time that I've spent. What worries me most is that what you claim you wanted to read is so very far from your original question, and from the solution that I posted

Comment: I may have been unclear. An object (any scalar variable that holds a reference) must be *blessed* into a class (a package) so that Perl knows where to pick up the method subroutines. However a class method call like `AaBb->method` above needs nothing as it specified the class directly. `@ISA` is only required when the initial class doesn't have a method of the required name, and its contents are used to search other classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***TL;DR*** [`use Moose`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose) instead of [`use Class::Accessor`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Accessor) will help a lot, and you shouldn't have to change your `has` definitions

As I wrote in my comment, you are asking [`Class::Accessor`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Accessor) — a module that easily creates accessor methods — to provide the full quorum of object-oriented features

I also think your thoughts about object-oriented inheritance are confused. I don't see anything wrong in what you have written, but having `Foo` as a *subclass* of `FooHack` is wrong thinking, and confused me as well as probably many others

There should  be a `Foo` base class and potentially multiple subclasses, like `FooHack`, `FooPlus`, `FooOnHorseback` etc.

Comment: `Foo` is nowhere a subclass of `FooHack`. It's not even a class.

Comment: Now I can however understand why this could be a problem: if a third party is trying to extend `Foo` as it was a class, bad things could happen.

Comment: @Dacav: It's sounding like you haven't explained your problem properly. What you have written *is* a Perl class as it has its own package name and a `new` constructor

Comment: I'm declaring `FooHack` as a class, but in `Foo` I'm not using a `use parent` statement nor blessing anything. I think `Foo` is not a class, but maybe I'm missing something. I'm quite new to Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a little bit nasty to tamper with a module like that - if it's not doing what you want, then normally you'd just write a new one.

You can take a class and extend it to make a new class - that's what you'd normally do if the class in question doesn't do what you need. Applying a hack to override the constructor is subverting the expectations of the class maintainer, and the road to brittle code, which is why you can't do it easily.

That said - normally as part of a constructor you'll call `bless` to instantiate the object into a class. By convention, this is done into the current class, using the `new` method. But there's no real reason you can't:

```
my $self = {};
bless ( $self, 'Foo' );
```

Just bear in mind that if your constructor doesn't do things this object is expecting to have happened, then you might break things.

Comment: Can you explain it better? How is it nasty? Also, I know about `bless`, but the point is taking advantage of the features of `Class::Accessor` as opposed to writing all accessors myself. `Accessor`, however, has exactly this problem: it doesn't allow you to do the expected things.

Comment: You can take a class and extend it to make a new class - that's what you'd nomally do if the class in question doesn't do what you need. Applying a hack to override the constructor is subverting the expectations of the class maintainer, and the road to brittle code, which is why you can't do it easily.

Comment: this is not a real override. It's like declaring a function, accidentally named `new` into a different package. That function returns an instance, and never messes with it again.

Comment: @Dacav: It's bad practice to alter the behaviour of a publicly-available module because your modification is then different from everyone else's. If someone wrote a program that required a given module for another purpose as well as yours then, if you apply changes for your own code, then that other purpose is likely to misbehave. You also have to incorporate any patches into your custom version while keeping the bespoke functionality

Comment: @Sobrique: I think you underplay the option of writing a custom module. If a complex requirement is fulfilled by a CPAN module except for an incompatible detail, then I would probably choose to  monkey-patch the current version after a `use External::Module 12.34` and to involve the module's author so that my requirement could be incorporated into a later publication

Comment: ...did I mention I'm writing the module? I'm not changing the behavior of someone else's module. I'm writing a proxy to the constructor of a class without even extending it... :)

Comment: @Dacav: If that is really all you are doing, then, within your subclass, all you need to write is `__SUPER__->new(@_)`